# How to add and show bookmarks in word online?

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office

There is a setting in word desktop version to show bookmarks as below:

> File=>Options=>Advanced=>Show bookmarks

But I couldn't find a similar setting in word in office online version (office.com), is there a way to see bookmarks in word online?

I've posted this same question [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_online/how-to-add-and-show-bookmarks-in-word-online/bc0bdc4d-86ef-4788-86b0-c84817008885?tm=1591862162968) as well:

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please post your query on http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Thanks, posted. bit.ly/3dR33W3

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-add-and-show-bookmarks-in-word-online/bc0bdc4d-86ef-4788-86b0-c84817008885. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: @macropod Done, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've got my answer, and it appears that since the online version of office only has a very limited functionality as compared to the full version installed on a PC or Mac, we can't add or see bookmarks in word online.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bookmarks in [Google Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Ccreate-a-bookmark%2Clink-to-a-bookmark) in this format

```
bookmark://_lo0imys6fm4j
```

and copy the **content** to the Microsoft Word Online. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can see bookmarks in word online by

```
View/Navigation/Headings
```

At first, for a while, the bookmarks pane only appears. Then it transforms into a pane with headers.

But you can view all bookmarks after

```
File/Save as/Download as PDF
```

By viewing the pdf version of your document.

To transform ordinary headers into bookmarks you can

[image: Click Styles]

Click "Styles"

[image]

Click "Apply Styles"

[image]

And instead "Book Title" style

[image]

use "Heading" style

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: use headings as bookmarks.

1. Highlight the text you want to use as a bookmark
2. Apply a heading style (you can create a new heading style based on existing/builtin heading styles and then customize). At this point the heading is effectively a bookmark
3. Highlight the text elsewhere in the document that you want to link to the heading/bookmark
4. Insert link using This Document:Headings to select the new heading/bookmark
5. Ignore the option for This Document:Bookmarks since it appears to be a feature gap